# Sign in to Chrome with google account

Tags: google-chrome

I started a new job yesterday

I want to access all my bookmarks, and other saved info in my google

I tried clicking on the profile photo in the top right then I get Sync is disabled , I click on it to sync and get the user id and password so I can sign in with my google but all I get is this page?!!

[image]

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?

How can I sign in with my google in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong here?

Nothing;  What you want is not possible on the machine you are using at work.

> How can I sign in with my google in Chrome?

Your IT Administrator has blocked this ability.  If you need assistance you should ask your IT Administrator for assistance.